# Atlassian STASH REST API 401

Tags: rest, pull-request, bitbucket-server

I'm trying to use the Stash REST API in order to get a list of all open pull requests using the URI https://stash.myserver.com/stash/rest/api/1.0/projects/TEST/repos/testrepo

But I always get a 401 Unauthorized with the following content:

```
{"errors":[{"context":null,"message":"You are not permitted to access this resource","exceptionName":"com.atlassian.stash.exception.AuthorisationException"}]}
```

I use HTTP Basic Auth and the user definitely has proper permission to the repository. It also works if I open the REST URL in the browser while I'm logged in or when I use the JSESSIONID-Cookie.

Is it possible that I need to enable basic auth in Stash? I couldn't find such an option in the admin settings.

Comment: this question is probably better asked on atlassian support channels, but basic auth should always be supported. check that your username/password is correct and that you're going through the proper steps for basic auth, e.g. base64-encoding "username:password", using the cookie name "Authorization", and giving the cookie a value of "Basic: " followed by the base64 encoding of your username & password.

Comment: Interested to know if you found an answer to your question @SchwaFa?

Comment: Can you provide more details about how you are trying to authenticate? It should work with basic auth out-of-the-box